# assign value to hidden field when checkbox checked javascript

Tags: hidden

I need to store the values in the hidden text field when I select any check box from the page

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked1" value="checked1" onselect="getvalue()">
<input type="checkbox" name="checked1" value="checked2" onselect="getvalue()">
<input type="checkbox" name="checked1" value="checked3" onselect="getvalue()">
```

When I any of the check box that will store into below hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery, and assuming you gave an id (here "myhidden") to your hidden input, you can do this :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    $('#myhidden').val($(this).val());
});
```

This fiddle demonstrates it : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/e6jpG/

Comment: OP specified JavaScript, not jQuery.