# Group of checkbox values to hidden text

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following group of checkboxes, and if a box is checked I want the value of the checkbox 'copied' to a hidden text field. So if the first, third and seventh box are checked the value of the hidden text field would be `1,3,7`

[I found this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716945/assign-value-to-hidden-field-when-checkbox-checked-javascript) but that only adds one value to the textfield.

```
<input id=myhidden value="">
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Tags <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form" role="menu">
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> Lokaal</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="2"> Nationaal</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="3"> Beide</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="4"> Onbekend</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="5"> Lokale partij</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="6"> CDA</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="7"> VVD</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="8"> D66</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="9"> PvdA</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="10"> SP</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="11"> GroenLinks</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="12"> ChristenUnie</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="13"> SGP</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="14"> PVV</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="15"> Partij voor de Dieren</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="16"> Overige landelijke partij</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="17"> Politieke actor</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="18"> Pers</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="19"> Kiezer</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="20"> tweet</li>
        <li><input class="checkbox" id="tagCheckbox" name="tags[]" type="checkbox" value="21"> user</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and the JS I tried

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    $('#myhidden').val($(this).val());
});
```

How do I do this?

**Update:** And when a checkbox is unchecked the value should be removed.

Comment: I'm guessing that you might have tried something that you'd like to share with us?

Comment: I did, I applied the solution in the opening post, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6jpG/117/)

Comment: Please post your code from the fiddle here, so that it is preserved for future visitors to SO.

Comment: OK good point @JayBlanchard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this simple code, you can do it :

```
//Bind change event
$('.checkbox').on('change', function(){
    //Select every checked input and build an array
    var values = $('.checkbox:checked').map(function(){
        //Return the value for the array
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    //Set the new val to you input
    $('#hiddenValue').val(values.join(','));

    //See the result
    console.log($('#hiddenValue').val())
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5JfLM/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one hidden field, and use the following code in the document ready event of jQuery.

**Javascript**

```
$(".checkbox").change(function(){

    var oChecked = new Array();

    $(".checkbox").each(function(index, val){
        if($(val).is(":checked"))
        oChecked.push($(val).val());
    });

    $("#hdnData").val(oChecked.join());
});
```

**Html**

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnData" />
```

You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/V2B6g/

I have also append the checked IDs to textarea so that you can feel the correctness.

Comment: @WilfredoP Are you beginner or professional? it also works when user uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: @RashminJaviya please do not be rude.

Comment: @WilfredoP he resets the array and loops through all of the checkboxes each time a change occurs. So he is wiping the slate and starting again with each change.

Comment: @RashminJaviya As far as i can see it does not display the results (only the comma seperator), check this: http://jsfiddle.net/e6jpG/118/. In stead of the hidden field i used a text field.

Comment: @RashminJaviya you should replace `$(val).attr("value")` with `$(val).val()` or even better `val.value`!

Comment: @RashminJaviya I found that, on testing, you code does not work. None of the values are added to the array oChecked.

Comment: @JayBlanchard as explained by WilfredoP i reset all values and codes works perfect you can check fiddle link.

Answer (score -1):

I made this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/6302/)** for you. Every time you click a checkbox, it will alert the result, which you can assign to your hidden field. Here is a code:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {

var result = "";

$('.checkbox').each(function() {


if ( this.checked ) { 
    if ( result.length > 0 ) {
    result+=",";
}
    result+=this.value;
}
});


alert("Assign value of your hidden field: " + result); 
});
```

Comment: But will it remove the value if it is unchecked? That is one of the OP's desires.

Comment: Yes it will only alert selected checkboxes. Please note that you still need to create the input field and add the result value to your field. Let me know if you need help with that.